# How to package and distribute required shared libraries on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

Scenario: I use OpenCV with FFmpeg in a commercial product that runs on Linux. Once compiled, my executable requires LGPL shared libraries in a huge dependency tree.

Instead of relying on a perfect match coming from a client machine's package manager, what options do I have on distributing my software?

Comment: Shipping it with your application sounds like the way forward. OpenCV doesn't need to be enormous if you build just the modules you need (but still around ~100 MB I would guess).

Comment: But how do I pack all the dependencies? In Windows, I'd just put the necessary DLLs in the main folder, but that obviously won't work here.

Comment: No, you need to link your application correctly. How you do this depends on your toolchain. You could also provide a wrapper script that sets `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before launching the application.

Comment: for embedded systems, you can use Yocto.

Comment: @Thomas - I'm not sure what you mean by "link your application correctly". Currently I'm compiling my product using dockcross with the added libraries downloaded using apt-get. Where I'm stuck is how to get all the needed files packed neatly with my product.

Comment: @codekaizer - Thanks for the link, very interesting platform, but designing a whole linux system might be something for later development.

Comment: You can put your libraries in the same folder as your executable (or a specific folder for your product under `/usr/lib` (for example)), you just have to set `-rpath` correctly to where everything will be installed.

Comment: @Galik - But how do I get all the needed libraries in place? The required packages are `libavcodec-dev:armhf libavformat-dev:armhf libswscale-dev:armhf libjpeg-dev:armhf libpng-dev:armhf libtiff-dev:armhf libdc1394-22:armhf libdc1394-22-dev:armhf libgtk-3-dev:armhf`, which in turn download and installs tens of packages into their default locations. How do I get all the required assets into "a specific folder for my product"?

Comment: @Nadav, there's actually prepared images like for RPi where you just need to update / add whatever packages you need. good luck!